# iPadOS13.1 input but no caret or autoscroll on focus

Tags: cordova, input, focus, caret, ipados

first time asking a question here, but I know there is so much knowledge accumulated here that I am hoping someone can help me.

The problem: In a cordova app on iPad using HTML5 I have input boxes on several divs in a horizontal layout within a parent div. Depending on the TranslateX of the parent different div are scrolled into the visual area (panorama with panels if you will)

On the first page inputboxes and textarea work normal. Tapping on it gives it the focus and you see a caret. If required the element scrolls into the visual space above the keyboard.

However has soon as the TranslateX of the parent element has changed tapping on the input boxes or textareas do not any longer show the caret and do not cause the element to scroll into view.

Needless to say that was not a problem on the previous iOS versions.

Anyone with clues, pointer, same experience, just anything at all would be greatly helpful, for the first time I am at a complete loss on how the solve this.

thank you and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found that as a workaround using left: *px; can replace transform: translateX(*px); and the caret will show again, and the element will gain focus and autoscroll above the keyboard again if required. Do note however that left - unlike transform:translate is not rendered by the graphical processor but by software and the user experience could be affected. Until resolved it may be a good workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

It have been fixed after updating to iOS 13.2